# Automated input tool to for QA testing? Play back keystrokes and mouse clicks

Tags: windows, macros, automation, automated-tests

Every time I test my program, I have to input a bunch of the same keystrokes and mouse clicks.

I am looking for a tool to automate this keyboard and mouse input. Similar to a macro recorder.

The tool needs to save the clicks and keystrokes I originally input.

When I want to QA my app, I will hit a keyboard shortcut and the mouse and keyboard inputs will be played back into the system again and again.

Is this a known type of QA testing? If so, what is it called? Who are the market leaders and are there any free versions available?

Comment: @Daniel: He's asking about a tool for software testing.  I think SO is the right place for this, not SU.

Comment: and I don't have access to SU.

Comment: Truly a pity this was closed.

Comment: The Not-Constructive Brigade strikes again! Another 20,000+ view great question is foolishly closed!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) to be great.

It is a very powerful tool, which does more than record just mouse clicks.  Using scripting, you can work with the controls in the application.

Comment: This is a nice tool. I compiled the macro and in my app's winform shown  event handler, I placed code to run it. So now when my app runs, it runs the playback. This is a huge time saver. Very cool. Thanks.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's working for you.

Comment: Hi @Jon. This application looks really nice, but I can't find the feature to record my mouse clicks/keystrokes and generate the script for me. It does have that feature right? Where can I find this?

Comment: Does this allows some kind of notification or alert if a test fails (certain conditions not met)?

Answer (score 9):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is good for this.  It's free, and can do lots of stuff from simple recording to complex macros.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.macro-recorder.com/

This works very well for me.  Even though it does cost some money to register, the demo version has full functionality with no constraints (as far as I know).  It converts your mouse and keystrokes into editable text files which are really convenient.

Comment: +1 for this, just tried out this and the other two above, this one was the easiest to get up and running.

Comment: Macro-recorder wasn't able to completely record my actions on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Perl's [Win32::GuiTest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest) for some [fun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAg7K_uwNZs), and also for serious testing. It does not record key strokes.